# ARC: how do I dealloc at the end of object life cycle?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to get my head around the life cycle of objects when using ARC. Essentially, I can't find what the best practice is to manage objects when declared globally in .h file:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController {
    NSArray *arrayA;
}

@property (strong) NSArray *arrayB;
```

Now from what I understand, both arrayA and arrayB are declared as strong, so they will be released when they are set to = nil, or changed to point to a different object. Do they also get released when the object of MyClass is released? Or do I have to override dealloc and set them all to nil? My guess is that the property will be released, but arrayA won't.

Using properties for everything doesn't make sense to me. What is the best practice for having a retained object that I need to use from different methods in the code, but keeping it private?

Comment: your code is fine. `arrayA` will be released when `MyClass` is released.

Answer (score 3):

> Do they also get released when the object of MyClass is released?

No.  They will get released automatically when the MyClass object is deallocated.  But this is good and it is what you want.

> Using properties for everything doesn't make sense to me. What is the best practice for having a retained object that I need to use from different methods in the code, but keeping it private?

You can use the instance variable directly.  ARC will put in the required retain/releases to make it all work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think what you're looking for are private properties. Declare them inside your .m file, using a private @interface as this:

```
@interface myClass()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *arrayWithSemanticName;
@end

@implementation myClass
// my class goes here
...
@end
```

:)

**Edit:**

It also works with Interface Builder, setting them as `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` works just fine, just as dragging them from IB would.